# Cassandra 3.10 Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native

Tags: cassandra, arm64, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra 3.10.0,running in ARM machine.

**Problem:**
  Cassandra Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native.

When I edit Cassandra-env.sh,I can not find "JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir".

with suggestion,randomly add JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/cassandra/tmp" in Cassandra-env.sh?

Comment: Is not clear what you need help. What do you mean by "with suggestion,randomly add JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=..."?

Comment: I am sorry not to describe the problem clearly .I see other blogs who meet the same problems,they say          "I added the options in cassandra-env.sh file. Added following statement -
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/cassandra/tmp" ".But I don't understand how to add.But now ,the problem hava solved ,changed the jna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention that you are running on an ARM (Advanced RISC Machine), I thought of this JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13072

Basically, the packaged JNA (4.0.0) module in 3.10 doesn't support AArch64 natively.  By the looks of the JIRA, it was patched and fixed in 3.11, so I would try using that version (Cassandra 3.11) instead.

If that doesn't work, try looking for a version of JNA which has support for AArch64 (http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.2.0/).